# Vim command equivalent to TextMate's 'Command+T'/'Go to File'?

Tags: vim, command

I have the directory of a Rails app open in Vim and would like to 'jump' to a particular file through a Vim command.

In TextMate I would type 'Command+T' and then the target destination file name.

Is there a similar command in Vim?

Thanks.

Comment: From the CLI, you can do this.  Ex: `vim +10 file.txt` would open file.txt and put you on line #10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a plugin that emulates this function called [Command-T](https://wincent.com/products/command-t). I use it and I'm very satisfied with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A note to others though, if you're on OSX (at least) you'll have to also install MacVim (which you can then subsequently set up to be accessible from the CLI).

Comment: You can also install vim via MacPorts. It's quick and painless.

Comment: If you are an OSX user, you might like PeepOpen. I'm not, so I never tried it, but I read it's very good (not free though). See Steve Losh's [fantastic post](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/#peepopen) about vim.

Answer (score 5):

I switched from CommandT to CtrlP. It a bit nicer overall than CommandT and is written in pure vim so it's easy to install (CommandT has ruby dependencies). Check it out here: http://kien.github.com/ctrlp.vim/

Answer (score 2):

There's `:e`, as well as many plugins that emulate TextMate more closely. [Here's one.](https://wincent.com/blog/bringing-textmate-style-command-t-to-vim)

Answer (score 1):

I use [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) as a supercharged alternative (file navigation + buffer navigation + buffer search) to Command-T (which I didn't like).

Also, yesterday I saw a "new" plugin on vim.org called [Quicksilver](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3617). You might give them a try.

Comment: Awesome -- will check these out. Thanks.

Comment: Checked out Quicksilver and it's not the same as Command-T - from what I can tell it just prompts you with the contents of the folder as you type, so you have to type a bit, <tab> type a bit <tab>, eventually coming up with the right path

Comment: Thank you. I've never tried it. Actually I switched from LustyExplorer to CtrlP. It rocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use : to access the command-prompt and then use the e command

`:e <file name>[enter]`

Comment: this does not search project wide, just in the local directory